# Help on PySCF library

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I am a student and I am trying to use qiskit nature in order to calculate the ground state energy of a molecule. My probelm is that when I try to run the simulation an error message comes out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [7] in <cell line: 4>
    res = calc.solve(es_problem)
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_nature/algorithms/ground_state_solvers/ground_state_eigensolver.py:93 in solve
    second_q_ops = problem.second_q_ops()
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_nature/problems/second_quantization/electronic/electronic_structure_problem.py:94 in second_q_ops
    driver_result = self.driver.run()
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_nature/drivers/second_quantization/electronic_structure_molecule_driver.py:173 in run
    driver_class = ElectronicStructureDriverType.driver_class_from_type(
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_nature/drivers/second_quantization/electronic_structure_molecule_driver.py:84 in driver_class_from_type
    class_obj.check_installed()
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit_nature/drivers/second_quantization/pyscfd/pyscfdriver.py:382 in check_installed
    raise MissingOptionalLibraryError(
MissingOptionalLibraryError: The 'PySCF' library is required to use 'PySCFDriver'. You can install it with 'pip install 'qiskit-nature[pyscf]''.  See https://pyscf.org/install.html.
```

I have installed PySCF using qiskit-nature[pyscf] and I also followed the instructions on pyscf.org , but the message keeps coming out, even if everything is already installed. Where I am doing the mistake?
The code I am trying to run is the tutorial: https://qiskit.org/documentation/nature/tutorials/03_ground_state_solvers.html

Comment: `pip show pyscf` shows its installed right in that environment you are running the tutorial. I have seen a couple of people say similar when they have been using the IBM Quantum Experience - for them re-installing qiskit-nature fixed things.

Comment: I gave this command and this is what comes out:      Name: pyscf
Version: 2.0.1
Summary: PySCF: Python-based Simulations of Chemistry Framework
Home-page: http://www.pyscf.org
Author: Qiming Sun
Author-email: osirpt.sun@gmail.com
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/natale/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: numpy, scipy, h5py
Required-by:             ; may the problem be that pyscf is in site-packages and qiskit is looking for it in other directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following step:

1. (uninstall both pakage)`!pip uninstall qiskit_nature --yes`
   `!pip uninstall pyscf --yes`
2. (check if uninstalled)`!pip show qiskit_nature` 
   `!pip show pyscf`
3. (install both package)`!pip install qiskit-nature[pyscf] -U`
   or
   (follow sequence)
   1.`!pip install qiskit-nature`
   2.`pip install pyscf`
4. do the step 2 again check both is installed
5. restart kernel, it should work like magic.

Comment: I tried but it says on both runs that requirements are already satisfied, so it skips the upgrading...

Comment: @NataleMatranga uninstall

Comment: It still doesn't work, I can't figure out why. I uninstalled and installed again, I tried to do this firstly via pip, then conda.

Comment: @NataleMatranga I edit my answer, I tried the method on IBM lab, it solved the issue.

Comment: I accept your answer, but it has not solved the problem... it keeps saying that I must install pyscf, but I checked as you said, they are installed...

Comment: Why qiskit is asking me to install packages if the IBM Quantum Lab works on cloud? Shouldn't it have all packages I need directly on cloud?

Comment: did you reinstall the associate package with my step? can you uninstall it? @NataleMatranga

Comment: Yes I reinstalled everything, and I can see where they are installed using "pip show ... "

Comment: @NataleMatranga did you uninstall it and check whether it is uninstalled successfully with pip show, and also restart the kernel is important after install it.

Comment: @NataleMatranga if still not working, consider log in and log out, doing the answer step again. if not working, follow instruction: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/troubleshooting#reset-your-notebook-pod.

Comment: @NataleMatranga if still not working, consider help on qiskit slack, because that is all the possible solution, and your case must be unique.

Comment: Thank you @poig , I appreciate how many advices are you giving to me. I will try on qiskit slack!

Answer (score 2):

`pyscf` doesn't support windows. For macos/linux or OSx please check this open issue [Issue with cmake during installation of pyscf #1684](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues/1684) on github. For MacOs you can check this open issue 
[PySCF-based tests segfault on Mac OS with Python 3.8
#1091](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-nature/issues/1091) too.